# How to set emacsclient background as Emacs background?

Tags: linux, emacs, elisp, emacsclient

I've got (in my .emacs)

```
(set-background-color "#101416")
(set-foreground-color "#f6f3e8")
```

And I've got 2 bindings:

```
alias ex='emacsclient -nw'
alias ec='emacsclient -c -a ""'
```

ex works fine to open client in terminal but when I want to open it as a frame I've got white background :(

Why and how can I use my dark background there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`set-background-color` and `set-foreground-color` only affect the current frame, and your `.emacs` file is not executed when running `emacsclient`.

Try setting the variable `default-frame-alist` ("Alist of default values for frame creation") instead:

```
(setq default-frame-alist
      '((background-color . "#101416")
        (foreground-color . "#f6f3e8")))
```